# Java MultiThreading banking application

Tags: multithreading

I have a doubt on Java MultiThreading. Suppose i am having a banking application.let us say i am having one controller like below.

```
public class BankAccount{

private String bankaccount;

private long balance;

getBalance(String bankaccount){

//code to get balance based on bankaccount number

this.balance=value; //value is the balance i get from database

}

updateAccount(long value){

 balance=balance-value;

//code to store balance in database
}
```

Let us say i have employed above code in a spring application
I have a scenario where for one particular account number the balance is 10000.A husband and wife are both trying to withdraw amount from the same account from 2 different ATMs. Since servers internally use Multi Threading,Synchronization is needed for the above scenario. I have following doubts

1) will the above 2 requests create 2 different objects of BankAccount class or only one object.

2) if it creates only 1 object how server can identify a different account number and create another object to it as updating one account number should not block updating some other account number.

Comment: Word of wisdom: don't run before you can walk.

Comment: I am very new to MultiThreading. Everyone will have their own timeline to learn things. Any kind of help is appreciated here instead of criticizing..

Comment: Nobody will give you lectures here. There're lot of materials on the net about the subject, so your homework first and then come back with exact problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It makes sense to implement a solution where only a single `BankAccount` instance is created for each account number.
2. You can use the `synchronized` keyword to synchronize access to each `BankAccount` instance individually. for example:

   ```
   BankAccount account = new BankAccount("1234567890");
   synchronized (account) {
       //perform a transaction here
       account.updateAccount(100);
   }
   ```

   This way, only a single thread can enter the synchronized block while other threads will block until the first thread exists the block.